# Best format to import in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, save, file-format, bitmap

I need to make a program for a client.  The program gets data from the web, template the data in an image and save the image.  The text in the produced image needs to be editable in photoshop.  What is the best file format for me to save into?

My first thought was svg but surprisingly photoshop does not support it.  What are my other alternative(html, eps, ...)?  What format would you prefer to have?

Many thanks

Didier

Comment: Photoshop is for best for *pixel images* and not *vector images*! SVG is a *scalable vector graphics* and you should rather use InkScape or Illustrator if you really want to work with vector images. `html` is a markup language understood by your browser and not an image. Btw, who on earth would gather data from the web and pack it into an image so that the text can be edited?

Comment: @halirutan `Btw, who on earth would gather data from the web and pack it into an image so that the text can be edited?`  apparently not you :)

Comment: Why does the text need to be editable outside of your application? Can you build a link to a page where users can edit the text and re export the file?

Comment: The pictures, are photos of horse races.  The customer wants to add the horse and driver names to the photo.  As the names can be quite complicated, it will very likely be re-edited in photoshop.

They are two reasons why the client wants the data to be fetched from the web.

1.  speed
2.  reduce typo risk

Comment: You should **really** ask adobe to allow svg imports.

Answer (score 3):

The formats that Photoshop supports editable text layers are psd, Tiff, psb, and Dicom.
For speed, use the psd format as it's the fastest format Photoshop uses.  If your worried about compatibility years down the road use Tiff, that standard is not going to be changed.